# include additional parameter via Directline using C# microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using c# and not javascript, I know how to implement the solution on javascript because I can send it in JSON. As far as using directline extension library on c#, how does one add a value to parameter passed on to directline channel. example:

```
{
      name:'namevalue';
   }

conversationClient.PostActivity(conversationId, new Models.activity()
{
   FromProperty = new Models.ChannelAccount(){Id="botnameapp"}
  ,Type="Message"
  ,Text = "hi bot!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, by using ChannelData. In my example I can use add channeldata like so.

```
conversationClient.PostActivity(conversationId, new Models.activity()
{
   FromProperty = new Models.ChannelAccount(){Id="botnameapp"}
  ,Type="Message"
  ,Text = "hi bot!"
  ,ChannelData = "User:Myname"
}
```

you can use these to store information about the user and create better experience.